# Why console output has question marks instead of Chinese characters in Windows Forms visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, console

My Windows Forms application shows ??? question marks. The output should be in Chinese characters. Here is photo:  [console output has question marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G82xU.jpg)

Comment: At some point of the journey from source to destination, your unicode string has been put through something that doesn't understand unicode

Comment: I have US localization, and the inside code has some Chinese characters, could it be the problem?

Comment: .NET uses UTF16 for strings, but there are several steps involved in e.g. reading a unicode file, storing unicode, printing it to some device. Your question is a bit confused because you talk about windows forms but then show a screenshot of the console and realistically we can't do anything without seeing the full code that reads this text in, stores it, and outputs it

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I'd suspect the issue may come from the console you're using, make sure it's using a UTF-8 codepage with a font that supports Chinese characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try the following code to show the Chinese character.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(936);
```

Comment: It seems that it is working, at the same time is 936 for Chines simplified of traditional characters?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Console encoding to utf8

```
 Console.OutputEncoding= Encoding.UTF8
```

But it might still not work with this code either

Console mode programs are stuck with non-Unicode support.  Necessarily so because their output can be redirected.  They're not going to display Chinese characters properly unless the system code page is Chinese.

The other programs you used that properly supported your Chinese input are Unicode enabled.  Which is the way to get ahead, write a real Windows program instead of console mode apps.  It isn't hard with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for the input. I tried Jack J Jun - MSFT and Bilal BWS method, and it appears to work. At the same time I solved this issue in the regional settings, in the administrative section by changing system locale to Chinese:

[image: changing system locale]

[image: changing system locale to Chinese]